# What is the quotient when $10^n +1$ is divided by $11$, $n$ odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have to find the quotient when $10^n + 1$ is divided by $11$, $n$ is odd.

Now writing $10^n + 1$ as $(11-1)^n + 1$ and expanding , i get the quotient as$Q=\sum_{r=1}^{n}{(-1)}^{r+1}\binom{n}{r}\cdot{11}^{r-1}$ but i have to prove that this $Q$ is actually equal to $9090...9091$ containing $n-1$ digits.

How do I prove it?

Comment: Can you prove that $10^{n} - (-1)^n$ is always divisible by $11$? This will help you, because then $(10^n + 1) - ((-1)^n+1))$ will be a multiple of $11$, and the second term is zero if $n$  is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{1+ x^{2n+1}}{1+x} &= 1 -x + x^2+\cdots + x^{2n}\\[-1em]
&= 1 + (x^2\!-\!x) + (x^4\!-\!x^3) + \cdots + x^{2n}\!-x^{2n-1}\\[.1em]
&= 1 + (x^2\!-\!x)\,(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{2n-2})\\[.1em]
&= 1 + 90(1010\cdots 0101)\ \ \ {\rm for}\ \ \ x=10 \\[.1em]
&=\qquad\! 9090\cdots 91
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks man brilliant. Very elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Use induction after noting that $10^{2n+1}+1=99\cdot 10^{2n-1}+(10^{2n-1}+1)$. Hence if $Q_n$ denotes the quotient of $10^{2n+1}+1$ divided by $11$ we have the recursive rule:
$$Q_n=9\cdot 10^{2n-1}+Q_{n-1}$$
that is, after starting with $Q_1=91$, at each step we
add "90" in front of the previous quotient (note $Q_n$ has $2n$ digits).

Comment: Your method is absolutely correct. Thank you for that. But is there any way I can prove $Q=9090...9091$ as I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: @idpd15 Well, I think that my answer is a proof by induction. The statement is: for $n\geq 1$ the quotient of $10^n+1$ divided by 11, $Q_n$, has $2n$ digits and it has the form $9090..91$ where "90" is repeated $n-1$ times

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for divisibility**

$$10 \equiv -1 \mod 11$$
$$\implies (10)^n \equiv (-1)^n \mod 11$$

if $n $ is odd,

$$\implies (10)^n +1\equiv 0 \mod 11$$

for the quotient, you can try by induction.